# I am trying to get this output but its showing wrong output from a website but my answer is correct

Tags: c++, types

With the help [from a website](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/c-tutorial-basic-data-types/problem) I am trying to solve the question of data types but I am getting wrong answer even my answer is right in output

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a;
    long b;
    char c;
    float d;
    double e;
    scanf(" %d %ld %c %f %lf",&a,&b,&c,&d,&e);
    printf(" %d \n %ld \n %c \n %0.3f \n %0.9lf",a,b,c,d,e);
    return 0;
}
```

inputs are
3 12345678912345 a 334.23 14049.30493  //space mean next value

expected output from website

```
3
12345678912345
a
334.230
14049.304930000
```

my output is

```
 3 
 12345678912345 
 a 
 334.230 
 14049.304930000
```

Comment: You need to show the expected output and the actual output, or nobody can help you.

Comment: Explain more. It's either right, or it's wrong. What's supposed to be the expected output? Also, I bet it's because of the extra spaces you're putting in the output.

Comment: With the edit, if the expected output has no new lines, why do you put in new lines?

Comment: What are all those `\n`s doing?

Comment: The website probably has a requirement on spaces before and after the numbers. Maybe you did not want a space before the \n

Comment: @MarkRansom sorry but now I have added it

Comment: Why did you add the whitespaces? That seems to be the problem.

Comment: Your expected and actual output are identical except for the leading spaces, so can you explain more thoroughly what it is you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks, everyone for helping me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made mistakes somewhere. You added extra spaces and did not add newline.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a;
    long b;
    char c;
    float d;
    double e;
    scanf("%d %ld %c %f %lf",&a,&b,&c,&d,&e);
    printf("%d\n%ld\n%c\n%0.3f\n%0.9lf\n",a,b,c,d,e);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: They did add newlines.